# Is it possible to use an undeclared variable in another variable

Tags: javascript, scope, var

I have always wondered this and every now and again it pops up.

```
var name = document.title;
var user = document.getElementsByClassName("class-name")[0].children[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;
var someArr = [];

for (var j = 0; j < document.getElementsByClassName("class-name")[0].children.length; j++) {
    if (user == name) {
        someArr.push(user)
    };
};

alert(someArr);
```

Now this is all made up (obviously) but see how the variable "user" is checking for children[j], well if I were to try use this code, it would come up with an error along the lines of "Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined". Now my question is: Is there a way to allow this code to work without giving an error message and not executing. I would use this for clean code in the if loop, like all variables are used for. This wouldn't be the only instance of the "user" variable being used either so it is very useful.

Thanks in advance,

Daniel.

Comment: what is `j` in the second line?  I think you mixed things up dude.

Comment: @vsync I guess it is `j` from the loop.

Comment: you are using j before it is defined. `document.getElementsByClassName("class-name")[0].children[undefined] = undefined`. That's where your error is coming from

Comment: No, you have to check with your own code to see whether there's a value before trying to use it as an object reference

Comment: First of all, as you predicted, it would throw error when you are declaring`user` variable since `j` is not defined. Then your logic would not work because for loop only loops within the `for` curly brackets `{}`. So, your user variable would never change unless you place your `user` variable declaration right after your for loop start.

Comment: Thanks all, you really helped a lot, I understand the trouble now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `j` variable will have `undefined` value if you use it *before* the `for` loop.

You could put it inside a function closure, but using variables like this does not make code readable in my opinion. What you can do is create a `getUser()` function and also cache the array of elements. Something like this:

```
var name = document.title;
var getUser = function(elem) {
   return elem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;
};
var initialArr = document.getElementsByClassName("class-name")[0].children;
var someArr = [];

for (var j = 0; j < initialArr.length; j++) {
    var user = getUser(initialArr[j]);
    if (user == name) {
        someArr.push(user)
    };
};

alert(someArr);
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that and giving an example of how it may work! I wasn't expecting a working answer so thanks for that :) Yeah I would have to agree with you, it just over complicates things, but if I am ever in the need for a working solution, this will do!